# Does loadThumbnail() from contentResolver loads thumbnails from the default Thumbnails folder?

Tags: android, image, thumbnails, android-contentresolver, mediastore

**What happens when we use the `contentResolver.loadThumbnail()` method in android ?**

-> Does it retrieve the thumbnail from the default `.thumbnails` **folder** present in android file system ?

`or`

-> Does any other process happens while using that ?

**Syntax :**

```
val cr = contentResolver
val bitmap = cr.loadThumbnail(uri, Size(45,45),null)
```